# Azure Devops - User Story - Settings - Additional Fields - "Due Date Not Present in Drop Down"

Tags: azure-devops

I've started a new position in my company and our senior developer created my own collection for me.  However, unlike the old collection I was used to working in, the new collection is causing me some trouble.  I cannot assign a Due Date in my User Story card... and Due Date does not appear under the Planning section that appears in the User Story guts.  The Due Date field is apparent if i create an Issue, but not User Story.  Anyone else experiencing this?

[Example of Settings and Additional fields dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHONI.png)

Comment: **Why** did they create a completely separate collection for you? That's overkill for a single user; a collection is effectively a completely separate instance of Azure DevOps Server. The issue is with the process template. Each collection has its own separate process templates, and a process in a given team project can be altered independently of the process template itself. So the process template is probably incorrect and will need to be corrected by an administrator.

Comment: @DanielMann Thank you sir!  There are going to be many more programmer/analysts joining the team, so it won't be overkill for long ;)

Answer (score 3):

The "**`Due Date`**" field is not available to the work item type **User Story** by default. It is only available to the work item type **`Issue`** (Agile) by default. For more details, see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops#date-and-iteration-path-fields).

If you want the "**`Due Date`**" field can be available to **User Story**, you need to manually add the this field to the layout of the work item type **User Story** in the process like as below image shows.

[image]

After adding the "**`Due Date`**" field to the layout, it can be available to **User Story**.

[image]

Comment: Hi @MacMiller, I have not heard from you for a long time. Just want to say hi and whether you have received my answer? Are the explanations in my answer helpful for you?
As explained in my answer, The "Due Date" field is not available to the work item type User Story by default. And you need to manually add the this field to the layout of the work item type User Story in the process.